# Setting bounds to a div, via keyboard control

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok, I have removed my code from here in favour of uploading the lot here:
http://www.project-vanquish.co.cc/jRPGrid-v0.4b/index.html

(please ignore any SQL errors)

- Clicking on a Grid-Node - moves the character to the position (boundries enabled)
- Dragging the character - moves to the position (boundries enabled)
- Using the keyboard cursor keys - moves the character (no boundries).

**I would like to set the boundries of the #character to be #map, via keyboard - the boundries work with the mouse**

Comment: Regarding your edit, you still are checking the `.left` of character to the `.top` of map.

Comment: oops, updated my code/question :)

Comment: Check my second answer for what I think the correct bounding should be. Try it out.

Comment: Hey Scott, cheers again but that code stops my character from moving left and right :( - updated question as well (again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I suspect the bounding is wrong. I have changed all the `if` statements to what I believe is correct to keep the character in the bounds of the map.

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(e){ //set the keydown function as...
    switch(e.which) 
        case 37:    $(characterName).css("background-image", "url(img/character-left.gif)");  //LEFT ARROW KEY
                    var character = $(characterName);
                    var map = $('#map');

                    if((character.offset().left - 40) >  map.offset().left) {
                        character.animate(
                            {
                                left: '-=40'
                            },
                            250,
                            function(){}
                        );
                    }
                    break;
        case 39:    $(characterName).css("background-image", "url(img/character-right.gif)"); //RIGHT ARROW KEY
                    var character = $(characterName);
                    var map = $('#map');

                    if((character.offset().right + 40) <  map.offset().right) {
                        character.animate(
                            {
                                left: '+=40'
                            },
                            250,
                            function(){}
                        );
                    }
                    break;
        case 38:    $(characterName).css("background-image", "url(img/character-up.gif)"); //UP ARROW KEY
                    var character = $(characterName);
                    var map = $('#map');

                    if((character.offset().top - 40) <  map.offset().top) {
                        character.animate(
                            {
                                top: '-=40'
                            },
                            250,
                            function(){}
                        );
                    }
                    break;
        case 40:    $(characterName).css("background-image", "url(img/character-down.gif)"); //DOWN ARROW KEY
                    var character = $(characterName);
                    var map = $('#map');

                    if((character.offset().bottom + 40) <  map.offset().bottom) {
                        character.animate(
                            {
                                top: '+=40'
                            },
                            250,
                            function(){}
                        );
                    }
                    break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not the most knowledgeable about JQuery, but my guess is every place that you set `top` with something like `'+=40'` it probable does not recognize the "+=" as an operator. You should probably set the `top` by getting the current value and doing the addition to it then assigning it back to `top`.

Comment: Unfortunetely, this isn't right. The +=40 *is* recognized as an operator. I think the problem is, that the jQuery thinks that the map.offset().left is more/less than what is should be. But I can't seem to fix it :(

Comment: As I look at the code, it seems odd that you are checking the `offset().left` for your `top` animation, and it seems odd that your check equation is the same: always a check for `character.offset().left - 40) >  map.offset().left` whether you are going to add or subtract a value